# Android SQLite NullPointer Exception and stack overflow exception

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

NUllpointer Exception and stack overflow exception on line which has has sql query.

display.java

```
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.widget.TextView;

  public class display extends Activity {
  private Context context;
  MyDBHandler helper

 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
    helper = new MyDBHandler(context);

    Bundle nameValue=getIntent().getExtras();
    String vname=nameValue.getString("Name");
    TextView tvname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVname);
    tvname.setText(vname);

    String dispname=helper.onSelect(vname);
    TextView tvaddress=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVaddress);
    tvaddress.setText(dispname);


  }
   /*public void onDisplay(){
    Bundle nameValue=getIntent().getExtras();
    if(nameValue==null){

    }
    String vname=nameValue.getString("Name");
    String dispname=helper.onSelect(vname);
    TextView tvaddress=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TVaddress);
    tvaddress.setText(dispname);
}*/




@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

MyDBHandler

```
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;

public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "productDB.db";
public static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
public static final String COLUMN_ADDRESS = "address";


private final Context myContext;
public MyDBHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
}


    @Override
     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(" +
            COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_ADDRESS + " TEXT " +
            ");";
    db.execSQL(query);
    String query1="INSERT INTO"+ TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(name,address) VALUES   
    ('name1,address1');";
    String query2="INSERT INTO"+ TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(name,address) VALUES   
    ('name2,address2');";
    db.execSQL(query1);
    db.execSQL(query2);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);
    onCreate(db);
}

public String onSelect(String sname){
    String dbString = "";
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String displayname= "SELECT address FROM"+ TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE "+       


    COLUMN_NAME + "=\""+ sname + "\";";
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(displayname, null);

   if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")) != null) {
           dbString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));
   }
    db.close();
    return dbString;
   }

   }
```

> NullPointerExcepion

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.arjun.tablesqlite/com.example.arjun.tablesqlite.display}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.arjun.tablesqlite.MyDBHandler.onSelect(MyDBHandler.java:57)
at com.example.arjun.tablesqlite.display.onCreate(display.java:27)
```

I'm getting NullPointerException at this line in MyDbHandler.java

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
```

and at this line in display.java....

```
String dispname=helper.onSelect(vname);
```

Comment: Can u do helper = new MyDBHandler(context); in onCreate after setContentView() and try, before that intialize the context to this

Comment: Unrelated, but you shouldn't `return` when `if(nameValue==null)`. That will exit the `onCreate` method, which is probably bad

Comment: @Raghavendra I'm getting the same error bro...

Comment: @arjun can u post your updated code.?

Comment: @cricket_007  even after making those correction I'm getting same error..

Comment: @Raghavendra I have updated bro...

Comment: @arjun can u double check your code to initialize MyDBHandler with my answer. You are still using new MyDBHandler(context); context is "null" here. Use "this".

Comment: I said unrelated - meaning it wouldn't fix the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try below onSelect Method and let me know any error in it:-

```
  public String onSelect(String sname) {
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String displayname = "SELECT address FROM" + TABLE_PRODUCTS + " WHERE " +


                COLUMN_NAME + "='" + sname + "'";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(displayname, null);

/*
        if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")) != null) {
            dbString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));
        }
*/
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address")) != null) {
                dbString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("address"));
            }else{
                dbString="No Address";
            }
        }else{
            dbString="No Address Found";
        }
        db.close();
        return dbString;
    }
```

And this:-

> MyDBHandler helper = new MyDBHandler(this);

Change this line like below

```
String query1="INSERT INTO "+ TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(name,address) VALUES   
    ('name1','address1');";
String query2="INSERT INTO "+ TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(name,address) VALUES   
    ('name2','address2')";
```

Your database query is like below(for reference):-

> INSERT INTO products (name,address) VALUES   ('name1','address1');

and your query build like this:-

> INSERT **INTOproducts** (name,address) VALUES   ('name1','address1');

so you have get below error.

Comment: I think **this.getWritableDatabase()** should solve your problem.

Comment: I had done those corretions..Now I'm getting this syntax error..... E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "INTOproducts": syntax error
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4100b2b8)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.arjun.tablesqlite/com.example.arjun.tablesqlite.display}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "INTOproducts": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTOproducts(name,address) VALUES ('name1,address1');

Comment: @arjun you have forget to add space after INTO in your insert query so please print query once and run it on external sqlite db so that you will able to get the error from queries

Comment: It worked bro!!

Comment: great,but always aware about white space insertion in query

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

You haven't initialized the context, and directly you have tried to intialize the DBHandler with that context, so it was throwing NLP.

```
public class display extends Activity {

MyDBHandler helper;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

    helper = new MyDBHandler(this);
   .... //your code
}
```

Comment: this has worked!!!But now I'm getting this ==>E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "INTOproducts": syntax error
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4100b2b8)
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.arjun.tablesqlite/com.example.arjun.tablesqlite.display}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "INTOproducts": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTOproducts(name,address) VALUES ('name1,address1');

Comment: @arjun give space after INTO in that query

Comment: @arjun try this: "INSERT INTO "+ TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(name,address) VALUES   
    ('name1,address1');" and String query2="INSERT INTO "+ TABLE_PRODUCTS + "(name,address) VALUES   
    ('name2,address2');";

Comment: @Raghavendra..it worked !!!Now I'm going to try similar concepts with php and mysql through servers....                                                                                                      I have a doubt bro.. should I memorize all the coding to develop an app?...